# HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid - Retrofit

Tags: android, iis, retrofit2, webapi

I am running a web API project in Visual Studio 2019. It runs fine on the localhost on my machine. when I go to make a GET /POST request, the request returns "400 bad requests invalid hostname".

Here is my Web API

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("forTest")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForTest()
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
```

I can hit the server in the postman, calling `https://localhost:44317/api/users/forTest`.

---

Here is my android studio setup,

1. APIClient

   ```
   public class APIClient {
       public static final String BASE_URL = "https://10.0.2.2:44317/api/";
       private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
       private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
       public static Retrofit getClient() {
           if (retrofit == null) {
           //Defining the Retrofit using Builder
           retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(BASE_URL) //This is the only mandatory call on Builder object.
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient().build())
               .build();
           }
           return retrofit;
       }

       public static OkHttpClient.Builder getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
           try {
               // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
               final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                       new X509TrustManager() {
                           @Override
                           public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] 
                             chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                           }

                           @Override
                           public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] 
                              chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                           }

                           @Override
                           public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                               return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                           }
                       }
               };

                   // Install the all-trusting trust manager
                   final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                   sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

                   // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
                   final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

                   OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                   builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
                   builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                       @Override
                       public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                           return true;
                       }
                   });
                   return builder;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
           }


   }
   ```
2. ApiService

   ```
   public interface ApiService {

       @POST("users/authenticate")
       Call<List<AuthData>> doLogin(@Body AuthBody authBody);

       @GET("users/forTest")
       Call<Boolean> ApiTest();
   ```

   }
3. MainActivity

   ```
   Retrofit retrofit = APIClient.getClient();
   ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

   Call<Boolean> call = apiService.ApiTest();

   call.enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call<Boolean> call, Response<Boolean> response) {
                   if(response.code() == 400){
                       try {
                           Log.i("TAG", response.errorBody().string());
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                   }
                   Log.i("TAG", "ok");
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable t) {
                   Log.i("TAG", t.getLocalizedMessage());
               }
           });
   ```

Response as,

> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3

Comment: oh my god. This is the solution. Thanks @LexLi

Answer (score 0):

According to @LexLi comment, I investigate the problem and find out the solution.

Orginal article - https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3